# uploading a local document using php

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to test a rest api for upload a local file to a https url. I am currently using curl to do it. The problem is that my POST in curl is getting converted into PUT (http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) mentions the same. 
To test from command line I'm using the following:

> curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization:Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXYYYYYzzzzzz" -H "Accept-Version: ~1" -H "Except: 100-continue" -H "Accept-Version: ~1 "  -T "somefile.pdf"  "https://abc-xyz.co/docs"

Output:

```
{"code":"BadMethod","message":"/docs does not support PUT"}
```

my php code:

```
$url = '"https://abc-xyz.co/docs';
$filepath = '/Users/me/Documents/somefile.pdf'; //mac path
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST" ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  
array('Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXYYYYYzzzzzz', 'Accept-Version: ~1', 'Except: 100-continue'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
$file = "@".$filepath;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$file); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if(!CURL_ERROR($ch))
  {      
  echo"\n The output is:".$response;
  }
else
  {
  echo "\nUpload failed ".curl_error($ch);
  exit;
  } 
curl_close($ch);
```

Output: I get parse error.

Can some one educate me with 3 things:

1. Can I use curl to do POST for https? if yes, how? and if no what should my approach be?
2. How to pass the file path name in my php? I tried "@".$filepath too but it still doesn't like it.
3. If I want to restrict my file upload type to be only pdf should i be using mime type? (application/pdf????)

Thanks,
DR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the commandline, see [post fileupload with curl](https://superuser.com/a/149335).

From PHP, see [the manual](http://nl.php.net/curl_setopt)

> The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation. To post a file, prepend a filename with @ and **use the full path**. The filetype can be explicitly specified by following the filename with the type in the format ';type=mimetype'. This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value. If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data.  As of PHP 5.2.0, **value must be an array if files are passed** to this option with the @ prefix.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,array('someuploadname'=> "@".$filepath));
```

Comment: Thank you Wrikken. I'll try what you have suggested.

Comment: I did look at post fileupload with curl. mentioned but the problem is that i'm sending file across https and the POST from Curl gets converted into "PUT" which my server doesn't support. I want help in how to upload a local file using POST over https.

Comment: @38172: then I cannot reproduce your problem. The posting with the array in php as mentioned just _works here (tm)_ ... and lo and behold, the superuser answer with curl works here too. Are you sure the problem isn't in a proxy / the receiving side?